# Begin was not declared in the scope for Generic Array Template Class

Tags: c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T, int N>
class Array {
    int size{N};
    T values{N};

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Array<T, N> &arr) {
        os << "[";
        for (const auto &val: arr.values)
            os << val << " ";
        os << "]" << std::endl;
        return os;
    }
public:
    Array() = default;
    Array(T value_added) {
        for(auto &value: values)
            value = value_added;
    }

    void fill(T data_value) {
        for (auto &value: values)
            value = data_value;
    }

    int get_size() const {
        return size;
    }

    T &operator[](int index) {
        return values[index];
    }
};

int main () {
    Array<int,2> nums;
    std::cout << "The size of nums is: " << nums.get_size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << nums << std::endl;
}
```

I am trying to create a generic array template class but I get the error Begin was not declared in the scope and it says it is due to the for (const auto &val: arr.values) loop.

Comment: your `T` is `int`, so as your `values` field. It's not `std::vector<int>` or any other iterable collection.

Comment: I still do not understand can you show me what I need to change?

Comment: This line `Array<int,2> nums;` makes `nums` initialized like this: `class Array { int size{2}; int values{2}; ... }` (just substitute `int` and `2`). Your `values` is not an array or any other collection at this point. It's just an `int` with value 2, and `int` cannot be iterated in `for`. You can declare `values` like `T values[N]` and so `values` would be an array of type `T` and size `N`.

Comment: I am sorry I am still confused can you change my code to show me, I can't put it together in my head when I read your sentence. I thought Int gave me the type I need to enter and 2 would be the space that is available.

Comment: As you write `Array<int,2> nums`, `T` becomes `int` and `N` becomes `2` right? Now in your class `int size{N}` becomes `int size{2}` and `T values{N}` becomes `int values{2}`. You see, `size` is just an integer variable with 2 inside, and `values` **IS JUST AN INTEGER TOO**. Change `T values{N}` to `T values[N]`, so it becomes `int values[2]`, that is `values` will be an **ARRAY** of integers of size 2.

Comment: OMG You're a life saver, when you stare at code for like hours you can't really tell the difference between a {} and a [] lol. Thank you so much.